# How to lump factors with only 2 levels using fct_lump?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to lump factors such that all but the most occurring level are lumped into "other". When having 3 or more levels, it works as expected:

```
> fct_lump(c("A", "A", "B", "C"), n = 1)
[1] A     A     Other Other
```

However, when I have a factor with only 2 levels, fct_lump does not work as intended. How can I create the "other" level when having only 2 levels in my factor such that the output becomes A A Other?

```
> fct_lump(c("A", "A", "B"), n = 1)
[1] A A B
```

In this small-scale example, it obviously can be achieved easily with other functions than fct_lump(). However, I have multiple thousand groups with different numbers of levels and the lumping also has to work when having less than three levels.

Comment: Can you try `fct_lump_lowfreq(c("A", "A", "B"))`

Comment: You can use `fct_lump(c("A", "A", "B"))` without the `n` or `prop` then it will call the `fct_lump_lowfreq`.   The way `fct_lump` works is based on the value of 'n', 'prop', i.e .it calls multiple functions `fct_lump_n`, `fct_lump_lowfreq`, `fct_lump_prop` based on whether the arguments are missing or not

Comment: In base R you can simply do `factor(c("A", "A", "B"), labels = c("A", "Other"))`

Comment: In the source code, there is a line which creates this issue `sum(rank > n) <= 1` returns TRUE and thus returns the `f`

Comment: This seems like a bug in `fct_lump_n`.